# C++ - List with logarithmic read, insertion at given position

Tags: c++, stl

I'm looking for data structure that behaves like a list, where we can insert an element at ANY given position and then read an element at ANY given position, where insertion and reading should be in logarithmic time. Is there something like this in the standard library or maybe I'm stuck with having to write this on my own (I know it can be implemented as a tree)?

Comment: Better performance are a const or they are fine? I mean, a faster implementation would not satisfy your requirements? To insert an element in a `std::list` takes a constant time, even though you spend a linear one to get an iterator, so I'm not sure if solves your problem.

Comment: When you say **insert an element at ANY given position**, then you are saying it can't be sorted correct?  I was thinking of a `std::map` but that keeps items sorted.

Comment: You said `list` but it sounds like you meant `vector`.  `insert` is too slow in `vector`.  I'm guessing you mean "vector like" in "read any position" of a `list` but that is not the obvious meaning of the phrase.

Comment: Sounds like you need some form of tree with no keys and with the weight of the subtree stored in each node.  Then finding any position is trivial log N.  An unbalancing insert at any position is trivial, but must be followed by a log N partial rebalance operation copied from your choice of standard tree algorithm.

Comment: Roughly how many items will be in your list? `vector` in practice outperforms everything else even for quite large values of N because contiguous storage is very cache-friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`std::multiset`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) behaves pretty much like the logarithmic `std::list` that you are looking for

- iteration is bidirectional
- insertion / reading are `O(log N)`

Note however (as pointed out by @SergeRogatch) that the "price" you pay for `O(log N)` lookup (instead of `O(N)` for `list`) `multiset` will order elements as they are inserted. This behaves differently than `std::list`. This also means that your elements need to be comparable using `std::less<>` or you need to provide your own comparator.

An alternative would be to use `std::unordered_multiset` (i.e. a hash table), which has `amortized O(1)` element acces, but then there is no deterministic order either. But again, then your elements need to be usable with `std::hash<>` or you need to write your own hash function.

Comment: It doesn't preserve the order of inserted items, but instead sorts the items by value.

Comment: @SergeRogatch thanks, I expanded the discussion a bit, to show what tradeoffs a choice of container entails.